# How do I switch from phone to tablet screen without any issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

I tried running my code which currently supports android phones on a 10 inch tablet. However, the app displays the error "Application currently not supported on this device".I was wondering how I can get it to work?
I tried switching  android:xlargescreen="false" > to true but that didn't fix it either.
Here's my android manifest code for the same:

```
 <supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"

        />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Also, in my splash activity where I am calling the alert if device isn't supported is :

```
/**
     * This method was originally used to detect if the device is supported or not
     * The device detection has been moved to the Android Manifest XML file
     * supports-screens tag
     * @return boolean true if device is supported
     */
    private boolean isDeviceSupported() {
        if (!Application.getAppResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isDeviceSupported)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.device_not_supported)).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


private void goToLoginActivity() {
        //Device detection has been moved to Android manifest XML file
        if (isDeviceSupported()) {
            LoginActivity.newInstance(this);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Any clue how I can get it to work on my 10 inch android tablet?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any permissions that are not available on the tablet like the telephone?

Comment: these are my permissions :   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

Set required false in uses-permissions and features in **AndroidManifest.xml**, like:

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="false"/>

  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>

  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
```

EDIT:

Also try remove

```
android:resizeable="false"
```

Is deprecated (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#resizeable), you can remove all block **supports-screens**, because default value is true.

Comment: that still doesnt work, it shows the alert message of device not supported on splash screen, anything i am missing?

Comment: on splash screen when application started? I think is programmable defect, please show me your R.bool.isDeviceSupported value